# Magento2:Admin Form

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent

In my custom module ,I want to display a form using ui component(instead of displaying a grid) on clicking a custom module admin menu. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this link](http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html) for creating admin form in magento 2